What is the best material for achieving a shiplap look in a bathroom?
I'm getting ready to do a bathroom remodel and my wife and I are considering adding shiplap around our tub and half shower wall similar to the example photo below. What would be the best material to go with here?

MDF: Would love to get away with this if we can, but I know MDF hates moisture… am I being too cautious in thinking MDF would be a no-go? Or have others used MDF with success?
Pine: OK with pine if that's the way to go in terms of moisture resistance, but unsure if it's moisture resistant enough to be in close proximity to a shower and tub. Anyone have any experience there?
PVC: If we do need to be super cautious about moisture, PVC is certainly an option, but I have zero experience with it. Has anyone used it? Can you tell it’s plastic after painting? Does it look as good as MDF?

Would appreciate insight anyone can share from experience.


Your question is mostly a matter of opinion (weighing appearance and durability), which makes it off topic. You're already aware of the moisture concern, so maybe revise to ask something specific about that.

please edit your post ... add a link to the source of the picture

I would think Hardie plank (or other cementatious board) would be ideal for this application, as cementatious board is already used for other bathroom purposes.

Absolutely no MDF in a bathroom.
The pine planks are a good idea. There will be a little expansion and contraction with the higher humidity in a bath, but they should work well.
I have used pine crown moulding in a bathroom and even over a shower and had no problems.
PVC, obviously more stable than the wood.  The pvc looks good once painted, however I cannot justify the higher price.
